# flutter send data to server (statusCode 500)

Tags: flutter, http

I am new to flutter and am trying to send data to the server. I followed a [tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data), but it did not work it give me a status code 500:

```
void signUp() async {
http.Response response = await http.post(
    "https://my-shop-server.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users/signup",

    body:jsonEncode(<String, String>{
    "name" :"test" ,
    "email" : "test180@gmail.com" ,
    "password" : "qwert" ,
    "passwordConfirm" : "qwert"
    })
);


print(response.body);
print(response.statusCode);
```

}

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was related to not enough length of password.

Answer (score -1):

You do not correctly pass the body. You need to jsonEncode your key-value pair like this:

```
http.Response response = await http.post(
    "https://my-shop-server.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users/signup",
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },

body:jsonEncode(<String, String>{
  "name" :"test" ,
  "email" : "test180@gmail.com" ,
  "password" : "qwert" ,
  "passwordConfirm" : "qwert" 
    });
```

Please carefully look [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data).

Comment: Sry i forget to put it ,  but i alrady use it and it not work , the same happen status code 500

Comment: Did you successfully get the result on Postman?

Comment: Is HTTP status code 200 on postman? First, you need to provide that on Postman. If it is 500 in Postman too, there may be another issue related to your server.

Comment: You need to add header data too. I edited the question.

Comment: i try with it and without it it s the same

Comment: i found the problem its appear that the pass is too short , thank u